# Como ocultar el teclado al cerrar un DialogFragment?

Tags: android, dialog-fragment

Tengo un Dialog fragment con dos edittext, el detalle es que al cancelar o cerrar el dialog el teclado queda a la vista y quiero evitar eso.

he intentado usar un metodo al cancelar:

```
@Override
public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
   // super.onCancel(dialog);
    hideKeyboard(getActivity());
}


public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

}
```

Peo no me  funciona el teclado siempre queda a la vista,estoy usando la API 28 de android.

Comment: El teclado virtual lo genero el DialogFragment?

Comment: @Elenasys si se genera en el DialogFragment

Answer (score 0):

Usa lo siguiente:

```
@Override
 public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog)
 {
    InputMethodManager imm =
         (InputMethodManager)editText.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (imm.isActive())
        imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

    super.onDismiss(dialog);
}
```